# Flask REST API record sender's IP address

Tags: rest, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have created a minimal REST API using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and Marshmallow. here is `app.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

# Initialize App
app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Database Setup
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
# Init db
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# Init marshmallow
ma = Marshmallow(app)


# Product Class/Model
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    qty = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, description, price, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.price = price
        self.qty = qty


# Product Schema
class ProductSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'qty')


# Init Schema
product_schema = ProductSchema()
products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)


# Create Product
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    name = request.json['name']
    description = request.json['description']
    price = request.json['price']
    qty = request.json['qty']

    new_product = Product(name, description, price, qty)

    db.session.add(new_product)
    db.session.commit()

    return product_schema.jsonify(new_product)


# Get All Products
@app.route('/receive', methods=['GET'])
def get_products():
    all_products = Product.query.all()
    result = products_schema.dump(all_products)
    return jsonify(result)


# Run the Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to extract the sender's IP address through the `GET` method. However, the sender's IP doesn't need to be part of the JSON payload.

Example: POST

```
{
    "name": "Product 1",
    "description": "This is product 1",
    "price": 120.00,
    "qty": 100
}
```

GET

```
{
    "ip": "<whatever-the-ip>"
    "name": "Product 1",
    "description": "This is product 1",
    "price": 120.00,
    "qty": 100
}
```

How do I implement this functionality in my code? I tried using `request.remote_addr`, but I am not getting what I expected.

Comment: whats wrong with request.remote_addr? Thats what I use, and I get the correct IP, local, production, etc... have you tried double checking it with request.user_agent? you might recognize the request isnt coming from the correct source this way

Comment: okay, thats fine but how do I implement it in my code in the way the question describes.

Comment: basically, you want to add the GET request's IP to the GET response?

Comment: yes, so when I send a GET request output will be thrown in the JSON format shown in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the response in the GET route any way you want before returning it, I added the request's IP to the response after serializing the db result like this:

```
# Get All Products
@app.route('/receive', methods=['GET'])
def get_products():
    all_products = Product.query.all()
    results = products_schema.dump(all_products)
    for product in results
        product.update({"ip": str(request.remote_addr)})
    return jsonify(results)
```

Comment: when running with it `result.update({"ip": str(request.remote_addr)})` throwing error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: oh yeah, I guess you're returning multiple products ("list of products", thus why the update fails). Precisely why I suggested separating the product details from the IP you want to return. Alternatively, you have to loop through all the products and add the IP to every product individually using the .update() function.

Comment: update will add a key-value pair into an existing dictionary (one product). I edited my answer so you can loop through all the products (a list, from your db), and it adds the IP to all the products.